# LDA with a categorical predictor variable

Tags: categorical-data, experiment-design, discriminant-analysis

I have a dataset with a categorical treatment (1 if treated, 0 if control) and many columns (34) of response variables.  Each column represents a species and its response (some measured abundance) to the presence or absence of the treatment.  Each row is a separate site; exactly half of them were treated and the other half were controls.  The experiment was replicated over two years.

I am interested in finding out which of these species respond to the treatment, so a LDA was suggested, but I am confused because my treatment is categorical and all of the examples I can find of LDA use continuous predictor variables.

So the data look like:

Treatment(0/1)    Site(ID#)      Year(1/2)    Species 1     Species 2    ...    Species 34

Can I use a LDA for this question?  If not, what sort of ordination is capable of accounting for categorical predictor variables?

Comment: Hi Laura, welcome to the site!  I don't think LDA is the right approach here; LDA wants continuous predictors and a categorical outcome. If I understand correctly, you want to know which species differ in abundance when the treatment is applied - which means you have categorical predictors and continuous outcomes! To me, that suggests something more like t-tests, at the most basic, or multilevel models/generalized estimating equations, if you want to get fancier and have explicit estimates of things like site and year effects.